# Proof of occupancy within 5 days Netherlands

Tags: netherlands, paperwork

I am going to move to Netherlands in Den Hague within 6 months, and I have been doing a lot of research about the process of getting all the necessary paper work and formalities in order. I'm an EU citizen (Finland) with an American spouse, and we are currently living in USA. I read that when you go get registered and to get the BSN number you have to have a Proof of Occupancy. My original plan was to tell my possible Airbnb.com address, but it seems I would be required to have an actual document where the landlord states I live there. How can I possibly be expected to secure a permanent apartment within 5 days of arrival? Any advice from someone who has experienced this themselves is greatly appreciated. So my question is: where or how, should I get "proof of occupancy" so I can register and get my BSN number in Den Hague Netherlands. Thank you.

Comment: The registration deadline under EU rules is 90 days after you arrive.  Do you have some other reason for which you need to register sooner than that?  Where does the 5-day deadline come from?